# In webpack, how can me make sure that the inline styles of svg files are overridden by the css styles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack, react-typescript

I am using webpack for bundling and running my typescript react and I am facing an issue where svg file's inline style is not being overridden by the css styles. This was working as intented when I was using create-react-app for bundling and running my project, but i want to switch to webpack. Is there any way in webpack config where i can use override the inline styles of svg files with css styling.

I have tried switching to different svg loaders to see if one of them allowed me to override the inline styles but I was not able to find one.
I have also tried changing the order of the loaders but this did not work as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.